# QMessageBox class giving more results then required

Tags: qt

I am using infinite while loop in my app from which i emitting a signal to call a slot in which dialog box is defined.

I am using msleep(5000) in my infinite loop.

Problem is when dialog box pops up first time and if i don't close it with in 5 seconds then another dialog box appears then another after 5 seconds and so on.

any help appreciated.

Comment: You could simply disconnect the signal when your slot is called.

Comment: I am emiting signal from another thread to main thread to deal with ui is that ok with this and defining my connect in class constructor

Comment: Yes, keeping the main thread for Ui and emitting signals to it from other threads is fine.

Comment: can i disconnect signal when my program control is in called slot

Comment: Yes, it just won't get called again.

Comment: pls post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the main thread for just the UI and use separate threads for processing. Using slots and signals between objects on different threads is fine, so long as the connection type is left as the default, Qt::AutoConnection, or set to Qt::QueuedConnection.

In order to prevent the message box popping up continually, disconnect the objects when you receive the signal in the connected slot.